# Are questions about security standards (e.g PCI-DSS) on topic?

Tags: discussion

Most of the questions I see on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions) seem to be about technical  security issues. Are questions about security standards compliance in scope?

**For example:**

> Our company is creating an ecommerce website that is hosted entirely offsite. Access to the remote servers will be restricted, with only a couple of admins accessing it (probably via a VPN).
>
> All credit card information is transmitted to and stored on the remote web server. In this situation how must we scope our PCI-DSS assessment (SAQ-D)? Should it
>
> 1. Only include our hosting service, the VPN, and the devices and admins that connect to the VPN. **OR**
> 2. Include our entire office LAN, even though it has no direct connection to the systems handling the credit card data.

Comment: While this q is definitely ontopic as @Rory said, you need to take any answer with a grain of disclaimer salt, that we are not your QSA. You would really need to get your QSA to sign off on it, whatever you do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a look at the site you will see we have lots of PCI questions, in fact there is a whole tag for that topic.